# UINavigationBar: Changing the font programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I'm implementing a UINavigationBar with some text on it but I want to change the font in the UINavigationBar text any of you knows if is posible to change font in the text programmatically?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ios 7 change navigation bar title font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791762/ios-7-change-navigation-bar-title-font)

Comment: you can easily find answer for this with little googling!!! It wont take much time as it took for you to post this questionn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From iOS 7 and later:**

```
 NSShadow* shadow = [NSShadow new];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor],
                    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f],
                  NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
                                                          }];
```