# Font size is not changed for title and subtitle in navigationItem.titleView

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

My goal is to use title and subtitle with different font sizes in navigation controller page title (title should be bigger, subtitle should be lower accordingly).

I found example of code to implement this. The only one problem is that font size is not applied - both title and subtitle have the same font size. Like the code for font size doesn't work.

How to fix that? Thank you

```
// prepare title label
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLight" size:19.0];
titleLabel.text = locationInfo;
[titleLabel sizeToFit];

// prepare subtitle label
UILabel *subtitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, 0, 0)];
subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
subtitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
subtitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLight" size:12.0];
subtitleLabel.text = dateInfo;
[subtitleLabel sizeToFit];

UIView *twoLineTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAX(subtitleLabel.frame.size.width, titleLabel.frame.size.width), 30)];
[twoLineTitleView addSubview:titleLabel];
[twoLineTitleView addSubview:subtitleLabel];

float widthDiff = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width - titleLabel.frame.size.width;

if (widthDiff > 0) {
    CGRect frame = titleLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = widthDiff / 2;
    titleLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);
} else{
    CGRect frame = subtitleLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = fabs(widthDiff) / 2;
    subtitleLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);
}

self.navigationItem.titleView = twoLineTitleView;
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS change navigation bar title font and color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791762/ios-change-navigation-bar-title-font-and-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's with the `setFont` method, not `.font`

```
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12.0]];
```

And also you have an error in the font name:

```
it's HelveticaNeue-Light
```

Comment: yes, the reason was with font name wrong )
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use **SetFont** instead of **Font**::

```
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:14.0]];
```